# Solve conflict between affinity mask and I/O affinity mask?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I executed this on one of our SQL Server machines:

`EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1`

And then executed `RECONFIGURE`. This presented me with the following error message:

> The affinity mask specified conflicts with the IO affinity mask
>   specified. Use the override option to force this configuration.

By executing `RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE` I can indeed force the configuration. But this is not a solution to the conflict mentioned in the error message.

The values in `sp_configure` are as follows:

```
name                 minimum        maximum       config_value   run_value
affinity I/O mask    -2147483648    2147483647    126            126
affinity mask        -2147483648    2147483647    126            126
```

I found some explanation [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2157114), but this basically just says "There should not be a conflict", nothing on how to solve it. Could someone knowledgeable please explain to me what this error message actually means and how/if I should try to solve it?

**Update 12/12/2012**

We couldn't find any reason for the setting of conflicting values for `affinity I/O mask` and `affinity mask`. I changed them back to the [default values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189631%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), 0 for both. After the reconfiguration `affinity mask` is set to 0 immediately, `affinity I/O mask` apparently requires a restart of the instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The 'affinity mask' and 'affinity I/O mask' configuration values of
> SQL Server should not conflict. Performance may suffer if you choose
> to affinitize a processor for both SQL Server worker thread scheduling
> and for I/O processing.

What is meant by the above statement is:

> DO NOT CONFIGURE SUCH THAT A PROCESSOR IS SET IN BOTH WORKER AND
> I/O MASKS!

It's stated in the documentation and is protected from a mistyped attempt by the error message and requirement to specify `WITH OVERRIDE` to force the change through. That was your warning that something bad could happen.

> Msg 5834, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The affinity mask specified
> conflicts with the IO affinity mask specified. Use the override option
> to force this configuration.

IO affinity masking is a rarely used optimisation, which offloads IO completion activity to a dedicated CPU. When set, a hidden scheduler is created that handles only IO operations for that instance. If you configure identical CPU and IO masks, the two schedulers will battle it out for CPU cycles and cause chaos.

The masks you've set are creating exactly that scenario with `1111110` specified for both.

If your intention is the more common requirement to dedicate CPUs to particular instances on a shared server, use just the CPU affinity mask and leave the IO mask as 0 (disabled).

I've encountered a mis-configured server with matching masks only once. I was put in front of it because the logs suddenly started filling up with the message we all dread to see:

> I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds to complete on file...

After resetting the IO mask and restarting, the server behaved perfectly and the error above was never seen again.

Useful references:

- Books Online - [affinity I/O mask Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/affinity-input-output-mask-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15).
- CSS - [How it works: IO Affinity Mask - Should I Use It?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/how-it-works-io-affinity-mask-should-i-use-it).

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot for your explanation! I will read up on this. It's not an option I configured myself, I just encountered it on one of our machines and wanted to know what's behind it.

Answer (score 0):

The “affinity I/O mask” and the “affinity64 I/O mask” options are used to bind SQL Server disk IO to specific CPUs. These options should rarely ever need to be used and their default value of “0” should not be changed unless you are an expert and have thoroughly tested the settings in a proper lab environment to see if they would be beneficial in your production environment.

The “affinity mask” and “affinity64 mask” options are used to bind processors to specific threads, which can sometimes boost performance on very busy SQL Servers with many cores. These two options are deprecated and should not be used if running SQL Server 2008 R2 and higher. If you are using SQL Server 2008 R2 or higher, use ALTER SERVER CONFIGURATION instead if you need similar functionality. So not change this setting unless you are an expert and have thoroughly tested the settings in a proper lab environment, as selecting the correct settings can be complex, and incorrect settings can lead to poor performance.